# Powershell Storing sqlResults into an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, powershell, dictionary

I have a power shell script that querys the database and returns two columns which are a key value pair.  Let's call them a & b.

How do I store this in a map to be called at a later date?  Below is mysql code, it runs and prints out columns out to the screen.

```
 $Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
 $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
 $Connection.Open()

 $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
 $DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
 $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
 $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
 $DataSet.Tables[0]
```

Just not sure how to store the key value pair in an mapto be used later.   Both columns are numeric.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run the following:

`$mySQLResults = $DataSet.Tables[0]`
`$mySQLResults`

Comment: Parse error when I run that.

Comment: Do I was thinking, I now have my dataset.  I want to store it in a hash table.  How do i loop though the results

Answer (score 0):

You want to cycle through each object in the results?

```
$Records = $DataSet.Tables[0]
$Records.Keys | ForEach-Object {$Record.$_}
```

This will allow you to iterate through the objects and run some bit of code for each of them.

For instance, I've got a hashtable like this:

```
$Records = [hashtable]@{'Name'='Stephen';'Hair'='Red'}
```

The results:

```
$Records.Keys | ForEach-Object {"object `$Records.$_ = $($Records.$_)"}
>object $Records.Hair = Red
>object $Records.Name = Stephen
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, please comment so that I can try to help you to a solution.

Comment: So i got it working the problem is now when try to add the data to the map, some of the key's are the same, but the values are different.  Is there a way to tell PS to ignore duplicates?

Comment: The error I get is that Exception calling add, with 2 arguments:  Items has alrady been added.

Comment: Key/value pairs must be unique.  So are you trying to update a field with a new value, or do you NOT want to add your new value if one already exists.